# Matplotlib custom colormap doesn't respect coloring

Tags: python, matplotlib

(**Old version of the question is below**)

I'm defining the following custom colormap where I assign the color white (`#ffffff`) to the float `zero_pt`.

```
import matplotlib.colors as col
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

zero_pt = 0.98181818181818181

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'mycmap', [(0, 'blue'), (zero_pt, 'white'), (1, 'red')])
```

But when I try to retrieve the hex color code from the same `zero_pt` value, I don't get `#ffffff` (i.e.: white) as I would expect:

```
rgb = cmap(zero_pt)[:3]
print(col.rgb2hex(rgb))
> u'#ffdcdc'
```

Why is this and how can I get around this issue?

---

**Old question here**

I need to define a custom colormap where negative values are displayed in blue, zero values in white, and positive values in red. The code is below, and the necessary data files here ([data.pkl](http://pastebin.com/zyb6ZUzC)) and here ([edges.pkl](http://pastebin.com/6M0QnV2m)).

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


with open('data.pkl', 'r') as f:
    H = pickle.load(f)
with open('edges.pkl', 'r') as f:
    edges = pickle.load(f)

# Define zero point for empty bins which should be colored in white.
zero_pt = 1. - H.max() / (H.max() - H.min())

print(H.min(), H.max(), zero_pt)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'mycmap', [(0, 'blue'), (zero_pt, 'white'), (1, 'red')])

Y, X = np.meshgrid(edges[0], edges[1])
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, H, cmap=cmap, vmin=H.min(), vmax=H.max())

plt.show()
```

This results in

[image]

If we inspect the `H` array, we see that there are a lot of zero values that *should* be displayed in white, that instead show in pink in the figure above.

This doesn't happen will all the data I use, it just happens sporadically. I presume the issue has something to do with rounding? Is there a way to force cases such as this one to show zero values in white as they should?

Comment: You're using the default number of colors when you generate the `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name, colors, N=256, gamma=1.0)`; I would try specifying `N=20` or so and see if the rounding was right for human perception. (You might need to round down `zero_pt` a bit so it lands in the interior of the white segment.)

Comment: Lowering `N` makes it worse (the color gets redder). If I use `N=500` I get `fffdfd` which is close enough to white, but I'm not sure what I am doing with that.

Comment: The docs for [LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) say `N is the number of rgb quantization levels`, so I guess I should increase that value if I need more precision?

Comment: Put in a colorbar to see what raising/lowering the `N` does. (It's the number of color segments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said in the comments you need to round the zero point value to a multiple of `1/N` if `N` is the number of colors in the colormap. Of course the difference between the zero point value and any other colors in the colormap must be bigger than `1/N`.

So here is a solution

```
import matplotlib.colors as col
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np 

N=256
zero_pt0 = 0.98181818181818181
zero_pt_rounded = np.ceil(zero_pt0*(N-1))/float(N-1)
print (zero_pt_rounded)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'mycmap', [(0, 'blue'), (zero_pt_rounded, 'white'), (1, 'red')], N=N)

# verify if original point zero_pt0 gives white color
rgb = cmap(zero_pt0)[:3]
print(col.rgb2hex(rgb))
```

Concerning your older question: It's not clear what the line `zero_pt = 1. - H.max() / (H.max() - H.min())` should do. 
I would guess that you need to put

```
data_value_for_white color = ...
zero_pt = (data_value_for_white color - H.min()) / (H.max() - H.min())
```

Furthermore, in order to make sure the desired value is covered by the white color in the colormap, we would need to make the two adjacent colors in the colormap white.

```
N = 256 # number of colors in the colormap
zero_pt0 = np.floor(zero_pt*(N-1))/float(N-1)
zero_pt1 = np.ceil(zero_pt*(N-1))/float(N-1)
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap',
         [(0, 'blue'), (zero_pt0, 'white'),(zero_pt1, 'white'), (1, 'red')], N=N)
```

A complete solution would therefore look like:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, rgb2hex


with open('data.pkl', 'r') as f:
    H = pickle.load(f)
with open('edges.pkl', 'r') as f:
    edges = pickle.load(f)

# Define zero point for empty bins which should be colored in white.
data_value_for_white_color = 0.
zero_pt = (data_value_for_white_color - H.min()) / float(H.max() - H.min())

N=256
zero_pt0 = np.floor(zero_pt*(N-1))/float(N-1)
zero_pt1 = np.ceil(zero_pt*(N-1))/float(N-1)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap',
     [(0, 'blue'), (zero_pt0, 'white'),(zero_pt1, 'white'), (1, 'red')], N=N)

Y, X = np.meshgrid(edges[0], edges[1])
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, H, cmap=cmap, vmin=H.min(), vmax=H.max())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The line `zero_pt = 1. - H.max() / (H.max() - H.min())` is there to make empty cells in the `pcolormesh` plot, be plotted white (see the "old" question). Your solution works in the sense that the rgb for `zero_pt` is returned as `#ffffff`, but it does not in the sense of the original question since all empty cells are now blue. since I modified the question, I will accept your answer nonetheless if no better solution is presented. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you using `zero_pt = (data_value_for_white color - H.min()) / (H.max() - H.min())` and only get the values as blues? I would guess that you're getting blues exactly because you use this stange line `zero_pt = 1. - H.max() / (H.max() - H.min())` which does not make much sense.

Comment: That line maps the 0. value in `H` (between `H.min()` and `H.max()`) to be white in the custom color map defined in the original question.

Comment: Anyways I edited the answer to show you that you should really use `zero_pt = (data_value_for_white_color - H.min()) / (H.max() - H.min())` to solve your problem.

Comment: That works great. Seeing that `data_value_for_white_color = 1. - H.max() / (H.max() - H.min())`, why does your last line work as expected but mine doesn't?

Comment: Because you need to normalize `data_value_for_white_color` to the range between 0 and 1 for the colormap

Comment: Well, just found an exception. Check [data.pkl](http://pastebin.com/dxx692Rz) and [edges.pkl](http://pastebin.com/PVEMEeKL), the result is [this](http://pasteboard.co/F4wslbS7v.png). The same issue mentioned in the original question, now reversed using your method.

Comment: This would be easier to understand with data designed as a test, Gabriel -- a simple gradient would be fine.

Comment: I see the problem now. It's not sufficient to make one single color in the colormap white, but you need two adjacent ones. See updated solution.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I tested the new code and it seems to work just fine, so I've accepted the answer (again) Thank you!